# The property IsDefaultFolder is always false when retrieving taskfolder list with outlook rest api

Tags: outlook-restapi

We are using the outlook-rest api to retrieve a list of taskfolders

GET: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/TaskFolders

I tried with a outlook.com and Office 365 account but the property IsDefaultFolder is always false for the default folder.

Can anyone reproduce ? Is this a bug ?

Thanks

See response below

{
    "@odata.context": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me/TaskFolders",
    "value": [{
        "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('xxx')/TaskFolders('ccc')",
        "Id": "iii",
        "ChangeKey": "ccc",
        "Name": "Taken",
        **"IsDefaultFolder": false,**
        "ParentGroupKey": "0006f0b7-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"
    }],
    "@odata.deltaLink": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/TaskFolders/?%24deltatoken=ddd"
}

Comment: It only seems to happen when there is only 1 folder. After adding a second folder then defaultFolder bool seems correct. Still very annoying bug.

Comment: I reproduce this on an Office 365 account, but not on an Outlook.com account. I'll report it.